# What is the function of PhLi in this reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, wittig-reactions

Can someone please explain the mechanism of the reaction when we add 2 moles of $  \ce{Ph3P}$ and $\ce{PhLi}$ to 1,2-dichloroethane.

I know this is a type of Wittig reaction but I am not able to figure out how the reaction will work out.

Answer (score 2):

I was wrong, this is not a Wittig reaction. Just posting the answer to let anybody who comes in hunt for this in the near future.

On googling for about an hour, I discovered that this is indeed a preparation of phosphonium ylide which is the witting reagent.

On adding $ \ce{Ph_3P} $ to 1,2-dichloroethane , $\ce{PhLi}$ acts as an catalyst and eliminates $\ce{HCl}$ from both the carbons resulting in a phosphonium di ylide.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not a catalyst.

Comment: Indeed it's just strong base, strong enough to deprotonate it twice. Catalysts aren't permanently destroyed in reactions which they're supposed to catalyse.